# C# SerialPort.IsOpen returns true when physically disconnected

Tags: c#, serial-port

C# SerialPort.IsOpen returns true when physically disconnected the serial cable on USB port.
Can any one help me how to overcome this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how serial ports work, they don't have a standard connection oriented protocol like TCP.  The "IsOpen" name choice was not accidental, it doesn't say "Connected" and only indicates that an Open() call succeeded and it might be a good idea to call the Close() method when your program exits.

With some luck, you ought to see the SerialPort.DsrHolding property *false* when you disconnect the cable or turn the device power off.  SerialPort.CtsHolding ought to indicate that the device is ready to receive data.  These hardware handshake signals are not always properly implemented and they can give a false indication when the cable is disconnected due to electrical noise.

There is otherwise never a good reason to have the cable disconnected and not for anybody to be aware of it, serial port cables are always short.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .yes you are right. My usb driver has no handshaking support to get the status of Dtr,Dsr,CTS. But is there any possibility to register an event to notify when the connected serial port cable is unplugged

Comment: SerialPort.PinChanged event.  But of course your driver killed that option.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Is there any windows calls to check the status of the serial port?

Comment: Sigh.  Of course.  The exact same ones that SerialPort provides.  The .NET class is just a wrapper for the Windows api.  There is no magic feature hidden behind the curtain, I would have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, serial ports have no standard way of knowing whether there's something on the other end or not. Some devices may pull some line high to indicate connection, but that all depends on the device, which means you'll have to implement that logic yourself.

I'd suggest you just try it and see if you get something back. If you have handshaking enabled you'll most likely get a timeout if there's no device on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague and for details would be helpfully but I will try anyways.

That is not what the IsOpen is for. If you want to know if the serial port is connected to something you will have to use the Read and Write TimeOut properties and put a try catch around any msg statements you send.

What I usually do is create a simple method that sends a query to the device on the serial port, then if it receives something back it's connected. if it times out something is wrong. I  call this method right after I open the serial port to make sure everything is working. After that you will have to rely on the time out exception every time you try to send something.

As for detecting if the USB cable has been unplugged that goes to a serial converter. if the convert is unplugged it should drop off the available come ports list. If it does this SerialPort should throw an exception when you try to open the port.

Answer (score 0):

IsOpen will always return true if you've opened the serial port.
It can merely tell you that whether you've opened the serial port before or not.

If you want to know whether your serial port has physically disconnected, try send a command string to your device where you can get respond from the command. 
Do it every 5 seconds or 10 seconds interval to keep an eye on the connection of your device.

The above is how I did it in my project, if there's any better way please comment below.

Answer (score -1):

What i did is to have 2 timers
First is shorter which is trying to find the port and init the device,if found i disable timer 1
The other is longer which try to read port.bytes to read ,if fail ,in catch, i enable timer 1

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33874508)